# How to combine a multiple custom objects in a single array in C#?

Tags: c#, arraylist, dynamic

I have design a custom object list,
and adding more details in here:

```
public static List<CustomList> MyLists = new List<CustomList>();
public class CustomList
{
    public string Name { get; set; } //
    public string Path{ get; set; } //
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
private void Form1_Load()
{
    CustomList[] list = new CustomList[5];
    list[0] = new CustomList
    {
        Name = "a1",
        Path = "c:/",
        Size = 1111,
        Value = 23
    };
    list[1] = new CustomList
    {
        Name = "a2",
        Path = "c:/",
        Size = 222,
        Value = 66
    };

    //add to MyLists
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
    {
        MyLists.Add(list[i]);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //show all MyLists
    foreach (CustomList element in MyLists)
    {
        if (element != null)
        Console.WriteLine(element.Size.ToString());
    }
}
```

In summary, I want to create a dynamic object arrays simulate like in PHP code:

```
<?php
$list = array(
    array(
        "name" => "a1",
        "Path" => "c:/",
        "Size" => 1111,
        "Value" => 23
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "a2",
        "Path" => "c:/",
        "Size" => 222,
        "Value" => 34
    ),

    //...
    // more than 10 arrays or any number sets ...
    //...
);
```

So I try to write a code in C#, 
I am also have added some code and modify some part again and again, 
but it is wrong, can I to fix it or it is not support in C#?

I create an array of Object class and assign anything to the array like this.

```
//it is a wrong code
CustomList[] list = new CustomList[](
new CustomList{
    Name = "a1",
    Path = "c:/",
    Size = 1111,
    Value = 23
},
new CustomList{
    Name = "a2",
    Path = "c:/",
    Size = 222,
    Value = 66
}
);
```

Comment: What is your actual objective? I mean, what problem is this code supposed to solve? I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Its not a wrong code, its would work just fine, what is the problem you are having

Comment: When I run last code, it display "CS1586  C# Array creation must have array size or array initializer"

Comment: @kkasp I see the problem now, use `{}` instead of `()` when initializing your array.

Comment: I wnat to assign a dynamic multiple lists by any size, and don't assign array size first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialized your array with `()` instead of `{}`.
The correct array initialization syntax is this one:

```
CustomList[] list = new CustomList[]
{
    new CustomList{
        Name = "a1",
        Path = "c:/",
        Size = 1111,
        Value = 23
    },
    new CustomList{
        Name = "a2",
        Path = "c:/",
        Size = 222,
        Value = 66
    }
};
```

or you can do:

```
CustomList[] list = new []
{
    new CustomList{
        Name = "a1",
        Path = "c:/",
        Size = 1111,
        Value = 23
    },
    new CustomList{
        Name = "a2",
        Path = "c:/",
        Size = 222,
        Value = 66
    }
};
```

or even:

```
var list = new []
{
    new CustomList{
        Name = "a1",
        Path = "c:/",
        Size = 1111,
        Value = 23
    },
    .  .  .
};
```

Comment: Good catch, easy to miss

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var list = new List<CustomList>() { 
    new CustomList{
        Name = "a1",
        Path = "c:/",
        Size = 1111,
        Value = 23
    },
    new CustomList{
        Name = "a2",
        Path = "c:/",
        Size = 222,
        Value = 66
    } 
    }

    var array = list.ToArray();
```